# JQuery Isotope container height issue w/ iDangero.us Swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

EDIT: The script is triggered and performing correctly when the window is being resized. Thanks a lot Сър Георги Демирев!

---

I've been pondering over a problem for a long while and I just can't seem to get a grip on it. On a photography portfolio site I use iDangero.us Swiper for a slideshow and JQuery Isotope for a thumbnail gallery.

Now, it works fine on Firefox and Chrome on Linux and Windows 7 alike.

However, on IE, Safari and Opera the grid items are showing in a vertical line, rather than a grid.

In order to locate the error I stripped the code from everything until I found out that Isotope stops this behaviour when I remove the Swiper part of the code.

The parent divs show to have 0 px height. Changing these to a fixed height (e.g. 1000px or 100%) doesn't change anything.

- Here's the original site: http://anthron.octans.uberspace.de/meta.php
- Here's a minimal example that still produces the error:
- http://anthron.octans.uberspace.de/meta.debug.php
- And the minimal source code: http://pastebin.com/H6t9bbNC

EDIT: Here's an implementation of Сър Георги Демирев's suggestion:

- http://anthron.octans.uberspace.de/meta.debug.2.php

It works now, however the margin-right after the grid items are gone and return only after window resize. However one step further now.

I'm very grateful for any suggestion, I'm quite clueless about this one...

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue on IE(8-11) on win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and the fact that images are stacked one under another probably means that the script is not loading. However, if you resize the browser window a little bit, the script is triggered and images are places the way they should.

Wrap this code

```
imagesLoaded( '#thumbnailgallery', function(){
    var $container = $('#thumbnailgallery');

      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonryHorizontal: {
        columnWidth: 240,
        rowHeight: 240,
        gutterwidth: 50},
      });
    });
```

in (document).ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    imagesLoaded( '#thumbnailgallery', function(){
    var $container = $('#thumbnailgallery');

      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonryHorizontal: {
        columnWidth: 240,
        rowHeight: 240,
        gutterwidth: 50},
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot for your comments. Very good observation, the script is indeed triggered upon window resize - I forgot to mention it. I wrapped the code in a $(document).ready call as you suggested and the error disappears. However, there's a new error now: The items appear in a horizontal row as they should, but without margin between them. The margin appears again upon window resize. Very strange...

Comment: PS: Here's the version with your suggestion implemented: http://anthron.octans.uberspace.de/meta.debug.2.php

Comment: I can't reproduce your page locally for some reason, if a jsfiddle demo was available I could help you better. I'm not familiar with the swiper plugin, however I still feel like parts of your script are not executed when the document is ready (same as before if you resize the window the script is triggered).

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back! I found that the second issue was caused by the following: I assigned the `margin`-value to the tag `isotope-item`. This tag is automatically created by the isotope-script and is true for all items that the script handles. Yet, apparently in some browsers this happens just a little bit too late, so that the margin is not assigned early enough. This was of course a lazy solution and a bad idea overall. I solved it by assigning the value inline to the specific object, it now works fine. Thanks again for the help!